# How to optimize code if ViewState turned off?

Tags: asp.net

```
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
         { }  
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {     
              if (!IsPostBack)  
              {  
                 DropDownList1.DataSource = SomeObject.GetData();
                 DropDownList1.DataBind();  
                } }  

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {  
    var selvalue = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;     
    DoSomething(selvalue); 
}
```

Please some body help me to make works properly this code if ViewState turned off.

Comment: What doesn't work? `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` is null?

Answer (score 0):

If you turn the viewstate off, then you need to rebind the data on every trip to the server and before the page initializes.

[Example of a dropdownlist without viewstate](http://brendan.enrick.com/post/Using-a-DropDownList-without-ViewState.aspx)